# Generic interface error

Tags: java, interface

Running the following code:

```
public static void get(FirebaseObject o, final Class<? extends  FirebaseObject> cls, final
  Callback<? extends FirebaseObject> callback) {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(o.getPath())
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            FirebaseObject o = dataSnapshot.getValue(cls);
            o.setKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            cls.cast(o);
            callback.onSuccess(cls.cast(o));
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            callback.onError(databaseError);
          }
        });
  }

  public interface Callback<F extends FirebaseObject> {
    void onSuccess(F firebaseObject);
    void onError(DatabaseError error);
  }
```

I get an error at `callback.onSuccess(cls.cast(o));`:

```
`onSuccess <capture ? extends FirebaseObject> in Callback cannot be applied to <capture ? extends FirebaseObject>`
```

Basically I'm trying to pass the `Class<? extends  FirebaseObject> cls` that was given in `onSuccess()`, after setting the key.

Is there a workaround this error? Or an alternative implementation to achieve the goal?

Comment: maybe you should generify the method parameter instead of using wildcards, i.e. `static <T extends FirebaseObject> void get(T o, final Class<T> cls, final Callback<T> callback)`

Comment: When you saying "running", I assume you mean "compiling"?

Comment: But please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because right now it's difficult to see the wood for the trees.

Comment: @1blustone You mean without `? extends`? I've tried that, but then when calling the method I can only call it with FirebaseObject, not with any sub classes of it.

Comment: @xsorifc28 I edited an example in comment (edit: Joe C just answered the same thing)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes, before running, intelliJ/Android studio shows this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final Class<? extends  FirebaseObject> cls,
final Callback<? extends FirebaseObject> callback
```

When you have these two parameters with separate `? extends` constraints, it's possible for them to refer to two different subclasses. If you have two subclasses `class A extends FirebaseObject` and `class B extends FirebaseObject`, the parameters could be

```
final Class<A> cls, final Class<B> callback
```

If that were the case then `callback.onSuccess(cls.cast(o))` wouldn't work because `cls.cast(o)` would return an `A` object and `onSuccess` would want a `B`.

If you intend these to refer to the same class, then you need to make that explicit by assigning it a name.

```
public static <T extends FirebaseObject> void get(
    FirebaseObject o, final Class<T> cls, final Callback<T> callback)
```

Comment: This explanation makes so much sense, I could not figure out what the error was trying to tell me since it just said "x cannot be applied to x".

Answer (score 2):

Your `callback` parameter might be incompatible with the `o` you are passing in.  For example, if `callback` is a `Callback<FirebaseObjectA>` yet `o` is a `FirebaseObjectB`, then things will blow up on runtime.

You should consider adding a type parameter to your method, like so:

```
public static <T extends FirebaseObject> void get(T o, final Class<T> cls, final Callback<T> callback) {
```